# Can a Chrome extension launch new Chrome windows under different user profiles?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Is there an API for a Chrome extension to launch and control new Chrome windows under different user profiles?

My understanding is that while an extension may be run under multiple user profiles simultaneously, these instances are isolated; they cannot communicate directly and an extension in one profile cannot access the windows/tabs/processes/etc of another profile.  Is this the case?

It seems like the best way to launch and control Chrome windows under multiple profiles is to use an approach based on the Remote Debugger API such as the ChromeDriver project.

For context, I'm interested in writing a tool to manage and launch predefined "bundles" of multiple Chrome windows, each with different URLs and screen positions, and each under a different profiles.  The attached screenshot shows an example desired state: three browsers, each in a separate profile, each at a different URL, with different devtools states, organized in a specific screen layout.  It is conceptually similar to [tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator#create-a-project).

[image: Multiple Chrome profiles in a predefined layout]

If I wanted to provide a Chrome-based UI for designing and managing these presaved layouts, it seems that I would need to provide a native shim that invokes new Chromes via chromedriver, and communicate with them via [native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging).  Is there a more direct API that I am missing?

It seems that the [proposed Profile Extension API](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/extensions/proposed-changes/apis-under-development/profile-extension-api) would do exactly what I'm interested in, but I don't see any discussion on the apps-dev@chromium.org list.

Answer (score 2):

If chrome allowed this it would be a huge security hole.
Chrome extensions are installed per user account so they shouldnt be able to see anything from other accounts.

Comment: This answer is correct. Obviously, there's nothing stopping you from using a remote server or native binary to orchestrate communication among different app/extension instances, but the CRX framework won't directly assist you with that.

Comment: Chrome doesn't advertise Profiles as a way to isolate or secure your data.  From a [Chrome support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en):   "The ability to add multiple users to Chrome is intended to provide a quick and simple way to set up personalized copies of Chrome for people who are already sharing Chrome on the same computer today. It isn’t intended to secure your data against other people using your computer. To truly protect your data from being seen by others, please use the built-in user accounts in your operating system of choice.

Comment: DThats just a disclaimer because having access to the o.s. account a user csn the many things including reading the o.s. folder where chrome stores stuff. Still would be considered a bug and problem if **code** (not a user) could access data from another chrome account.